# C# Can't get char from string property

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, char

I have **Property** of a class that receives string values from a string field. I need to check if the string value of the property has the first two **char** values equal or different from the first **char** values of a group of strings from an array. Then if no matches, I need to replace the first 2 characters of the string received by the Property

So, in my case: I decided to use the Property **BookID** (*from class Book*) to read the first character from a string that this property receives, and compare it with the first character of each string from the array **categoryCodes**. If none of the first characters match (*and here is where I am stuck*) I need to replace the first 2 characters of the string that the Property **BookID** has, with 'M' and 'I'. I am getting an error that honestly don't understand at all, and spent hours trying to solve it, but I have no idea.
HELP! S.O.S

```
class Book
    {
        public static string[] categoryCodes = {"CS", "IS", "SE", "SO", "MI"};
        public static string[] categoryNames = { "Computer Science", "Information System", "Security", "Society", "Miscellaneous" };

        private string bookId;
        private string categoryNameOfBook;

        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
        public int NumOfPages { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public string BookID
        {
            get { return bookId; }
            set
            {                
                bookId = value;
                CategoryCheckSet();
            }
        }
        public string CategoryNameOfBook
        {
            get { return categoryNameOfBook; }            
        }

        private void CategoryCheckSet()
        {            
            if (BookID[0] != categoryCodes[0][0] 
                && BookID[0] != categoryCodes[1][0] 
                && BookID[0] != categoryCodes[2][0] 
                && BookID[0] != categoryCodes[2][0] 
                && BookID[0] != categoryCodes[3][0])
            {
                BookID[0] = categoryCodes[4][0]; //ERROR HERE: BookID[0], MESSAGE: Property 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
            }
        }
    }
```

What Am I doing wrong here?
Can I access a *string* inside of a **Property** just by using the Property itself?
How can I replace specific characters in a *string* that Property receives?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might have an XY problem.....

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't understand your comment. 'XY' problem......??

Comment: BookID is not an array, my idea to handle it would be something like

`string temp = BookID;
BookID = $"{categoryCodes[4][0]}{temp.Substring(2)}"`

You could probably also consider changing BookID[0] to BookID.Substring(0,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [string indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=netcore-3.1) is *read only*, which means you can't set the char via its indexer

```
public char this[int index] { get; }
```

**The longer story**

Strings are *immutable* (an unchangeable object) and *Interned*.

*Interning* is just a fancy way of saying strings are stored with only one copy of each distinct string value in a table to reduce allocations. It's easy to see why a *string* then need to be *immutable*. Being able to set the *indexer* or change it would lead to all sorts of weird issues.

---

You will either need to convert your `BookID` to a `char` *array* with `ToCharArray` then `Concat` it back, or use [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) or C# 8 *Range notation* and rebuild the `string` by some other means

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
> specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

```
var chars = BookID.ToCharArray();
chars[0] = categoryCodes[4][0];
BookID = string.Concat(chars);

// or

BookID = categoryCodes[4][0] + BookID.Substring(1);

// or if you like interpolation 

BookID = $"{categoryCodes[4][0]}{BookID.Substring(1)}"

// or if you like C# 8 ranges

BookID = categoryCodes[4][0] + BookID[1..]
```

Comment: Absolutely agree, you cannot change a char inside a string using the indexer, you need either to use string.Replace() or create a new string starting with the new characters and add to it the rest of the previous...